# Problems installing Ruby with RVM: rvm install 1.8.7, rvm install 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problems installing ruby with rvm.  I am currently running Mac OS X 10.6.8.
Having loaded rvm, and restarting Terminal, I've run the scripts:

```
$ rvm get latest 
(rvm update --head returned an error message: "ERROR: rvm update has been removed. See 'rvm get' and rvm 'rubygems' CLI API instead")

$ rvm reload
<RVM reloaded!>
```

Now I get problems:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
```

Get the following in return:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #fetching

ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracted to /Users/user/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352 (already extracted)
Applying patch 'stdout-rouge-fix' (located at /Users/user/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch)

ERROR: Error running 'patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f <"/Users/user/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch"', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p352/patch.apply.stdout-rouge-fix.log

ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #configuring

ERROR: Error running 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 CFLAGS='-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp' CCFLAGS='-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe' CXXFLAGS='-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe' LDFLAGS='-arch x86_64 -bind_at_load' LDSHARED='cc -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace' ./configure --prefix=/Users/calebballoch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc  ', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.8.7-p352/configure.log

ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Furthermore, when I install the 1.9.2 version, I get similar problems.

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7
```

Which returns:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #fetching 

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracted to /Users/user/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290 (already extracted)

Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/user/.rvm/archives

Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/user/.rvm/src

Configuring yaml in /Users/user/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.

ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/user/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/configure.log

Compiling yaml in /Users/user/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.

ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.log
Installing yaml to /Users/user/.rvm/usr

ERROR: Error running 'make install', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.install.log

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #configuring 

ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/user/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/configure.log

ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound to me like you don't have a compiler or make tools installed. First do you have make and gcc installed ? These come with XCode, if you don't have XCode install, install it then try again

Else do

```
cat /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.install.log
```

paste this output here.